# Modify Schema in Titan DB. Delete, update

Tags: schema, titan

As per the documentation its not clear we can add,delete but only rename the elements and also can we modify relations, property etc ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please ask direct questions.

Comment: okay i have a dataset and i want to load that dataset into titanDB and i don't know how yo do that and why i am doing it because to check whether we can modify schema in titanDB

Answer (score 1):

The [Titan documentation](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/schema.html#_changing_schema_elements) states:

> The definition of an edge label, property key, or vertex label cannot
>   be changed once its committed into the graph.

The [SchemaManager](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/current/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/schema/SchemaManager.html) interface shows all of the methods that are available. As you can see, you can create the schema elements, but there are no methods for delete or modify/update.